# Create method in forms.Form

Tags: django, forms, view, save

My questions is, can I create methods in a form?

I want to create a method in a UserChangeForm it should control some things.
And how can I call this method then in the `save()` if commit?
In the `forms.form` I must create a save() too?

I tried this:

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.Form):
    #fields for the form

    def create_club_contact(self):
        user = super(UserChangeForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if information is None:
           #create clubcontact 
        else:
           #update clubcontact 
        return clubcontact

    def clean_password2(self):
        #check password
        return password2

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        user = TennisClub(link=data['link'], name=data['name'])
        user.save()
        contact = self.create_club_contact()
        user.club_contact = contact
        user.save()
```

On this way I'm always getting this Error

> 'super' object has no attribute 'save'

I think the forms.Form needs a save() method, but I don't know, how to do it right. 
In the docs, I have not seen such a example.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: First of all, do not apologize for asking a question and for being a novice. There as nothing wrong about it. In the line `contact = self.create_club_contact()` you call a method within `save()`. That's it, where is actually your problem? You shouldn't make `user.save()` twice, just once in the end. And correct this please: `name =data['name']` to `name=data['name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.member = False

    # example of a method with return statement
    def my_method(self):
        return something

    # example for a void method, no return value
    def another_method(self):
        self.member = True

    def save(self):
        my_variable = self.my_method()
        self.another_method()
        # continue with your logic
```

EDIT:

I think you don't have the problem with creating methods and calling them. The above is probably clear to you. But it seems that you have another problem, but you can't question it right.

Your form inherits from `Form`. The parent class `Form` has a method `save()` and you want to override it.

Put this in the end of your method `save()` and try again:

```
return super(UserChangeForm, self).save()
```